# Ansible using the when condition as a simple while (to stop at the first matching criteria)

Tags: loops, ansible, yaml

I'm looking for a way to stop the when condition at the first matching criteria. I have a dict which I'm looping through which looks like this.

```
"jsondata": {
        "app_storage_size": "30GB", 
        "cust_database_storage_size": "20GB", 
        "supp_size": "5GB", 
        "sys_storage_size": "15GB", 
        "temp_database_storage_size": "10GB", 
        "transaction_log_storage_size": "10GB"
```

I have loop which looks like this.

```
- name: Convert 1st disk size info and appending to jsondata
  vars:
    # Get first system disk
    disk: '{{ ansible_facts.disks[1] }}'

    # New key/value to append to existing jsondata dict with disk number
    new_item: "{ '{{ item.key }}': { 'disknumber': '1' } }"

    # Show disk size in Gibibytes
    disksize_1_gib: '{{ (disk.size/1024|pow(3))|round|int }}GB'  # returns "224GB" (value in GiB)
  set_fact:
    jsondata: "{{ jsondata | combine(new_item, recursive=true)}}"
  when: disksize_1_gib == item.value
  loop: "{{ jsondata | dict2items}}"
```

In this I'm trying to combine the matching disk size on the vm with the matching jsondata dict to replace the **size** with the corresponding **disknumber**. Everything works fine UNTIL there are disks with the same size. In that case all the matching values in the jsondata will be assigned to 1 disknumber. **EDIT2:** This is for the 1st disk and there are 6 of this task for the 6 disks.

To give you an example:

```
"jsondata": {
        "app_storage_size": {
            "disknumber": "1"
        }, 
        "cust_database_storage_size": {
            "disknumber": "4"
        }, 
        "supp_size": {
            "disknumber": "6"
        }, 
        "sys_storage_size": {
            "disknumber": "3"
        }, 
        "temp_database_storage_size": {
            "disknumber": "2"
        }, 
        "transaction_log_storage_size": {
            "disknumber": "2"
        }
    }
```

You can see here that 2 of them have been assigned the same disknumber because of matching size.

**EDIT:**
The 1st input is the jsondata dictionary which is given in the first code section (which can have matching disk sizes), and I'm getting the disk information on the vm with the win_disk_facts module which gives me the size of all disks on the vm. I'm matching the 1st disksize with the jsondata disksizes in a loop to add the disknumber (in this case '1') to the jsondata dictionary. For output I'd like to have the jsondata with unique disknumbers (so in case of my example above, "temp_database_storage_size" or "transaction_log_storage_size" should be 5).

So the question remains, is there a way to somewhat make the when conditional to stop at the first match?

Comment: what is the result you want to have?

Comment: The 1st input is the jsondata dictionary which is given in the first code section (which can have matching disk sizes), and I'm getting the disk information on the vm with the win_disk_facts module which gives me the size of all disks on the vm. I'm matching the 1st disksize with the jsondata disksizes in a loop to add the disknumber (in this case '1') to the jsondata dictionary.
For output I'd like to have the jsondata with unique disknumbers (so in case of my example above, "temp_database_storage_size" or "transaction_log_storage_size" should be 5). Let me know if this helps. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry one more missing information: the example is for the 1st disk, there is 5 more of this exact task for all 6 disks (with the difference in using the ansible_facts.disks[X] with incremental values).